# "Assert" on quick spinner don't work [Selenium IDE]

Tags: selenium, selenium-ide

I have Something like that on my selenium IDE :

```
click | button
assert element present | id=spinner
assert element present | id=label
```

I click on a button and a spinner is shown (an element HTML is created) for the loading, after that the spinner element is deleted and replace by a text element.

My problem is this first `assert` command don't see this spinner may be it's too fast for it (2-3 sec)… In case where the spinner is during more time as 10 sec and not after a click it's working.

So have you an idea ?

My tries :

- Replace `click` by a `send key`
- Place n transition command between `click` and the first `assert`

Thanks

Ps : Mozilla V56.0, Selenium IDE V3.12.3

Edit : To be more explicit, I want to assert my spinner is present

Comment: Your question is a bit vague to me. Do you want to assert that the spinner is / was present? Or is the spinner irrelevant

Comment: Sorry, yes i want to assert the spinner is / was present

Comment: The button starts a loading page and spinner is visible during this loading… My assert is only done after the loading so when spinner isn't visible

Answer (score 0):

You use wrong command, see [assert](https://www.seleniumhq.org/selenium-ide/docs/en/api/commands/#assert) command description. To check spinner presence you should use [assert element present](https://www.seleniumhq.org/selenium-ide/docs/en/api/commands/#assert-element-present) command like this:

`assert element present | id=spinner |`

Comment: yes sorry i wasn't clear, this is what i do. My code was too simplified, i'll change that. But this assert element present is executed too late…

Comment: Also you can try `wait for element visible` or `wait for element present` command to check presence of spinner.

Comment: No it doesn't work… It is waiting but without detect my spinner

Comment: I think the page loading after the button click blocks the commands, but that spinner is present only during this loading